# Akka Streams cycle example in docs not working

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to build an Akka Stream with a simple cycle in it. After reading the documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/scala/stream-graphs.html#graph-cycles-liveness-and-deadlocks) and having no luck with it I tried to just copy the example code as a starting base, but that also doesn't work. The code compiles (after including a source which is missing from the example) but nothing is printed out. It looks as though something is backpressuring for ever but I don't understand why.

Here's my code, any help would be much appreciated:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ActorMaterializerSettings}
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.ClosedShape

object Simulate {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Define simulation flowgraph
    val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
      import b._
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val source  = add(Source.repeat[Int](1))
      val zip     = add(ZipWith[Int, Int, Int]((left, right) => left))
      val bcast   = add(Broadcast[Int](2))
      val concat  = add(Concat[Int]())
      val start   = add(Source.single[Int](0))
      val sink    = add(Sink.ignore)

      source ~> zip.in0
                zip.out.map { s => println(s); s } ~> bcast ~> sink
                            concat        <~          bcast
                zip.in1 <~  concat        <~          start
      ClosedShape
    })

    g.run()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: it actually seems that the problem is not adding a buffer, but the order inlets / outlets were declared.

This works:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val source = Source.repeat(1)
  val start = Source.single(0)

  val zip = b.add(ZipWith((left: Int, right: Int) => left))
  val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val concat = b.add(Concat[Int]())

  source ~> zip.in0
            zip.out.map { s => println(s); s } ~> bcast ~> Sink.ignore
            zip.in1 <~ concat <~ start
                       concat <~ bcast
  ClosedShape
})

g.run()
```

The order of `zip.in1 <~ concat <~ start` and `concat <~ bcast` is consistent with what's on the docs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the same thing, nothing flows through the graph.

Comment: This is strange. I actually got it working. Let me paste all the code in the answer.

Comment: @Oli I've updated the answer. It seems that defining the second inlet for the `zip` before flowing the outlet of `Broadcast` into `Concat` does the trick. I'm not sure what the exact reason for this though.

Comment: This is really strange, I just copied your code to my project and I'm still getting nothing! My project is a standard SBT project, is your's the same?

Comment: I was using a Gradle project as a template but that shouldn't make a difference. If you don't get the bottom example from the akka docs working probably it could be an issue with your environment?

Comment: Maybe, I'm using akka stream 2.0.3 and akka 2.4.2, with Scala 2.11.7. Is that similar to your setup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105386/discussion-between-oli-and-manub).

Comment: Didn't realise akka 2.4.2 contains akka streams! replacing akka-stream-experimental 2.0.3 with akka-stream 2.4.2 did the trick. Thanks @manub